# SQL query issue with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could you please let me know how to left join two different tables based on the condition? I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.flag,
       B.fname,
       B.lname
FROM   Table1 A
       CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(A.flag, 0) = 0 THEN LEFT
       JOIN Table2 B
            ON  B.id = A.id
                ELSE
       LEFT JOIN Table3 B
            ON  B.id = A.id
```

Comment: You're going to need some dynamic SQL here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id,
       A.flag,
       CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(A.flag, 0) = 0 THEN B1.fname
            ELSE B2.fname
       END as fname,
       CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(A.flag, 0) = 0 THEN B1.lname
            ELSE B2.lname
       END as lname
FROM   Table1 A
       LEFT JOIN Table2 B1
            ON  B1.id = A.id
       LEFT JOIN Table3 B2
            ON  B2.id = A.id
```

Try this:

```
 CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(A.flag, 0) = 0 THEN B1.fname + ' ' + B1.lname
            ELSE B2.fname + ' ' + B2.lname
        END as name
```

Comment: It looks like this should do it. Thanks

Comment: How do I join lname and fname? fname + ' ' + name fullname. I am getting ambiguous column error when I join fname and lname.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  But you can join both tables and then choose the value you want in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT A.id, A.flag,
       (case when coalesce(A.flag, 0) = 0 then b.fname else c.fname end) as fname,
       (case when coalesce(A.flag, 0) = 0 then B.lname else c.lname end) as lname
FROM Table1 A left outer join
     Table2 B
     on B.id = A.id left outer join
     Table3 C
     on c.id = A.id
```

This will produce extra rows if there are multiple rows in Table2 or Table3 for any ids.

Just as an alternative, which would usually be less efficient, you could also do:

```
select a.id, a.flag,
       MAX(case when coalesce(A.flag, 0) = 0 and which = 'b' or
                     coalesce(A.flag, 0) <> 0 and which = 'c'
                then b.fname
           end) as fname,
       MAX(case when coalesce(A.flag, 0) = 0 and which = 'b' or
                     coalesce(A.flag, 0) <> 0 and which = 'c'
                then b.lname
           end) as lname
from table1 A left outer join
     ((select b.*, 'b' as which from table2 b)
      union all
      (select c.*, 'c' as which from table3 c)
     ) b
group by a.id, a.flag
```

The `group by` would eliminate unwanted duplicates.

Comment: You also may need to filter out rows that have no correlating row in either of the joined tables.  The OP's desired result is not clear in this scenario.  A simple `WHERE B.fname IS NOT NULL OR C.fname IS NOT NULL` should work if that is desired.

Comment: Thank you. TableB is a DRAFT table. TableB and TableC columns are same. There could be a same person exist in both tables. I am trying to return the results based on the FLAG.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly.  However, there is a totally unintuitive way that actually works.  You do left joins using different conditions, and coalesce.  Something like this.

```
select a.id
, coalesce(c.name, b.name, 'no name found') name

from tableA a left join tableB b on a.field1 = b.field1
left join tableC c on a.field1 = c.field2

etc
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Look at the other answer . . . the condition is not on whether the first join works, it is based on a flag in the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table to join is dependent on the A.flag, you should apply that knowledge in the join clause...

```
SELECT A.id, A.flag, 
    fname = coalesce(t2.fname, t3.fname), 
    lname = coalesce(t2.lname, t3.lname)
FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.id = A.id and isnull(A.flag, 0) = 0
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 on t3.id = A.id and isnull(A.flag, 0) = 1
```